# Cosa sono "i trasparenti" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Un matrimonio in provincia* della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani) ho letto:

> La sala vasta, quadrata, chiara, troppo chiara, perché non c'erano né tende, né cortine, né **trasparenti alle finestre**, era mobigliata con un divano addossato alla parete principale di contro alle finestre, quattro poltrone due a destra e due a sinistra del divano, appoggiate al muro, ed otto sedie lungo le pareti laterali, quattro per parte.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "trasparenti" in questa frase. È chiaro che si tratta di un sostantivo. Ho cercato il [vocabolo "trasparente" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trasparente/), ma nessuna delle accezioni come sostantivo sembra essere qualcosa da mettere alle finestre. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono "i trasparenti" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sul Treccani trovo questa accezione alla voce [*trasparente*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trasparente/) come sostantivo:

> **e.** Nella scena teatrale, schermo di garza o di rete dipinta che, visibile se illuminato dal davanti, diventa invisibile se illuminato da dietro, usato per ottenere effetti speciali o mutamenti di scena a vista.

Quindi “tenda leggera”, probabilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me in questo contesto sci si riferisce ai **vetri**

EDIT:
La mia interpretazione è evidentemente sbagliata, concordo con l'interpretazione di @egreg